# Como mudar as cores de uma implementação Jquery?

Tags: css

Observe o arquivo abaixo;

https://jsfiddle.net/9ub9yk7t/1/

Eu já tentei de várias maneira mudar as cores que pertence a tag H3 de azul para vermelho e não estou conseguindo, eu conseguir mudar as outras coisas, mas não conseguir mudar a cor de Azul para vermelho, alguém poderia por favor me dá uma ajuda?

Comment: Olhe se era isto que você precisava https://jsfiddle.net/9ub9yk7t/44/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que seria isto.. utilize o container (div#accordion) para facilitar a seleção dos elementos que vc quer estilizar.

PS: Creio que seria mais simples se você utilizasse css para reestilizar os elementos.

```js
var accordion = $('#accordion');

accordion.children('h3').css({
 'background': 'red',
  'border': '1px solid red'
});

accordion.children('div').css({
'background': '#fcf5eb',
'color': '#3f3f40',

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.structure.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
    Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
    ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
    lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
    et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
    faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
    mauris vel est.
    </p>
    <p>
    Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
    inceptos himenaeos.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
 



 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Só mais uma dúvida! tem como conseguir tirar essa borda azul que se encontra em cada aba? eu tentei assim, mas não conseguir
'accordion.children('h3:hover').css '

Comment: É so setar o estilo do border.. n? vou editar a resposta.

Comment: poderia por favor editar a resposta.

Comment: @wladyband já editei removendo as bordas, da uma olhada no $(accordion).children('h3').css(... , deixei a border da mesma cor.. caso voce quiser remover a borda. seta como 'none';

Comment: muito obrigado :)

Comment: Não foi nada, caso a resposta tenha sido satisfatória, por favor, marque-a como aceita. Obrigado.